# Creating Image Hotspots

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I maybe just going about this the wrong way I don't know. I have a PNG and it is 1000x1000 pixels. I is shaped like a pentagon and in each section I have a box. What I want to do is have each box that is part of the PNG to be a clickable box. I have tried to research how to do this but I could not find any answer to this question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am visual studio 2010 and creating a visual basic windows application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by checking the mouse event args when the png is clicked.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx

[Here](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/netc2.htm) is a tutorial on event arguments and how to pass them to functions or subroutines.

I believe [this](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/eventhandler_2.htm) is exactly what you are trying to do...

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown( _
   ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
   Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
   Dim myPicBox As PictureBox = sender
   Select Case e.Y / myPicBox.Height
      Case Is > 2 / 3
         Debug.WriteLine("It's in the bottom third")
      Case Is > 1 / 3
         Debug.WriteLine("It's in the middle third")
      Case Else
         Debug.WriteLine("It's in the top third")
   End Select
End Sub
```

-Reference to the last website.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `MouseMove` Event and `MouseDown`  or `MouseClick` Events and check if the `Cursor` is within a certain Rectangle  by using the Contains Method like this. It will need to be expanded to handle multiple HotSpots.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim hotspot1 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(25, 25, 50, 50)

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
        If hotspot1.Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then
            Beep()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If hotspot1.Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then
            If Cursor <> Cursors.Hand Then Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        Else
            If Cursor <> Cursors.Default Then Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, that is even more precise to what I need. I was trying to figure out a way to "cut" into the PNG and it was not working out for me at all.